# How do you clear the R console in OS X (or Ubuntu)

Tags: r, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function to Clear the Console in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260340/function-to-clear-the-console-in-r)

In bash, its like this:

```
$ clear
```

And I believe it's CTL-L in the Windows version of R. But how do you clear the R console in Unix-type R Consoles? Do you need to write a special function and what would that look like?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in R for Mac OS X

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in RStudio for Mac OS X

Comment: Here's a handy tip for finding any menu command in OS X: cmd-shift-/ to bring up the Help menu, type "clear", see where the relevant menu items are.

Answer (score 16):

Since you ask for Ubuntu as well, it's simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> from a standard gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 10):

I discovered that you call also type unix commands with the `system()` function.

```
system('clear')
```

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, my console to [R](http://www.r-project.org) is provided by [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org) on whichever platform I use -- and as that is within [Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org), it is always Ctrl-l (or C-l in the common shorthand for Emacs).

Answer (score 2):

Create this function:

```
cls <- function() cat(rep("\n",100))
```

Then call it:

```
cls()
```

Compatible with Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: insert 100 newlines == clear? false

Comment: There is a much better way to do this.  Rather than put 100 new lines, which is not really a clear, you can also print out the code for cntl-L.

Comment: if you wanna get fancy: `clear <- function() { cat(rep("\n", Sys.getenv("LINES"))); }`. But, yeah, while not a true "clear-screen," it does clear the screen and add a useful bit of space between code segments.